# Fixing programatically trx intrinsic gas too low on Arbitrum

Tags: python, arbitrum

I am trying to simply approve spending of a token by uni router like that:

```
MAX_APPROVAL_HEX = "0x" + "f" * 64
MAX_APPROVAL_INT = int(MAX_APPROVAL_HEX, 16)
params = {
    'from': wallet_address,
    'value': 0,
    'gas': 21_000,
    'gasPrice': 100_000_000,
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address),
}

func = token_contract.functions.approve(router_address, MAX_APPROVAL_INT)

txn = func.build_transaction(params)
signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, private_key)
txn_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

But I keep having "Intrinsic Gas Too Low". I tried increasing both gasPrice and gas, till the point it says "insufficient funds for gas * price + value".
i have 0.0234 ETH in my wallet, so enough to cover that trx at least.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Because how Arbitrum operates as layer two, the relationship between gas price and gas units and ETH is not straightforward.

The error is likely because you are hardcoding `gasPrice` value. I recommend using the default gas settings from your JSON-RPC node to get started.

Comment: i tried with 'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price, but same error...